# How to write generic typings for HOC with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I am writing the typings for an existing UI library which has a Base component which takes in `Element` as a string and does `<Element {...props}`
What is the correct way to type it?

I have tried writing a generic type with

```
type AllTypes = HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement> | HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement> // ... And other HTML element types
type BaseTypes <T extends AllTypes> = {
    Element: string;
    props: T;
    className?: string;
    baseClassName?: string;
}


export const BaseComponent = <T extends AllTypes>({
    Element = "div",
    baseClassName,
    className,
    ...props
}: BaseTypes<T> ) => {
    const classNames = [];

    if (baseClassName) {
        classNames.push(baseClassName);
    }
    if (className) {
        classNames.push(className);
    }



    return (
        <Element 
            className={classNames.join(' ')}
            {...props }
        />
    )
}
```

and on the other side

```
type newType = {
    Element: string;
    props: HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>,
    className?: string;
    baseClassName?:string;
}

const InputField = (props: newType): ReactElement => {
    return (
        <BaseComponent<HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>>
            Element="input"
            baseClassName="ff-input"
            {...props}
        />
    );
};

export default InputField;
```

I am getting errors like cannot assign `{className:string}` to IntrinsicAttributes.

I would like to know the correct way to type the BaseComponent such that the props types are decided based on the Element value. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use just a plain string as `Element` with JSX. If you want to use a string you could swap to doing this...

```js
React.createElement(Element, { ...props, className: classNames.join(' ') }, null);
```

Alternatively you can amend the type of Element to be `ElementType<any>`, for example...

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { HTMLProps, ReactElement, ElementType } from 'react';

export type BaseProps = {
    Element: ElementType<any>;
    className?: string;
    baseClassName?: string;
}

export const BaseComponent = <T extends {}>({
    Element = "div",
    baseClassName,
    className,
    ...props
}: T & BaseProps) => {
    const classNames = [];

    if (baseClassName) {
        classNames.push(baseClassName);
    }
    if (className) {
        classNames.push(className);
    }

    return <Element { ...{...props, className: classNames.join(' ') } } />;
}

const InputField = (props: HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>): ReactElement => {
    return (
        <BaseComponent<HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>>
            Element="input"
            baseClassName="ff-input"
            {...props}
        />
    );
};

export default InputField;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did make slight modifications to make it work. But this approach definitely works. I got it to work without the double spread operator.